# How to uninstall versions of Java openJDK

Tags: java, uninstall, openjdk

I am using Linux Mint XFCE 20.

Recently I installed Java by running `sudo apt-get install openjdk` and it automatically installed versions 8 and 11 of both JRE and JDK, including JRE headless.

It turns out that I needed only openjdk 16 to run what I wanted to, and having other versions of java are kinda pointless. My main issue is that programs default to version 8 and I can't seem to fix it.

So how can I uninstall both versions 11 and 8 and just keep 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unwanted versions can be removed by name:

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt remove openjdk-11-jdk
```

They are installed with different packages.

You can see all the openjdk packages available with this command:

```
sudo apt update
apt-cache search openjdk
```

You can see all openjdk packages in your system with:

```
dpkg -l | grep openjdk
```

*Note: I am a RedHat user, not a Mint expert but this is pretty much the same on every distro. I just checked the package names on Mint for those commands to work.*

Answer (score 1):

With the provided instructions I was able to uninstall everything I don't need. I also had to uninstall headless versions separately with commands:

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-8-jre-headless
sudo apt remove openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

Comment: This is not quite how these sites work, these aren't discussion forums but Q&A sites. Please take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out Questions and Answers in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) section to learn how they differ. To say "thanks" you just need to accept the answer. Don't be surprised if this gets deleted - this is more a comment than an actual answer to your question, and [commenting in an answer isn't allowed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). [From Review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/390171)